# Electrostatic potential in a semiconductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, semiconductor-physics

I was thinking about a very simple question. Imagine we have a semiconductor "embedded by vacuum". Regarding this situation, I was thinking what is the potential felt by the electron approaching (from the outside region) the interface between semiconductor and vacuum. My naive answer would be the [workfunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function) of this semiconductor, but I'm not sure. Any comments?

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.7.3541

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra could you please comment on this? Thanks.